# How to responsively stack semantic-ui grid columns within row at non-mobile breakpoint

Tags: css, semantic-ui, grid-layout, semantic-ui-react

I'm attempting to have two equal-width columns stack between `computer` and `tablet` sizes. I'm doing this in semantic-ui-react, but here's what I have so far in rendered HTML:

```
<div class="ui stackable two column grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="eight wide computer sixteen wide mobile sixteen wide tablet column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/assets/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" class="ui image" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="eight wide computer sixteen wide mobile sixteen wide tablet column">
      <div class="ui segment">
        <img src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/assets/images/wireframe/paragraph.png" class="ui image" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w535s2fb/1/))

The issue I've run up against is that there is no vertical gutter at `tablet` size, but there is one at `mobile` size.

I assume I should not be using the `stackable` property since it is hard-coded to impact `mobile` size only. What should I do in its place?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing your column size definitions. So the first thing is I would remove the size definition on your Grid component.

You are correct that stackable specifically targets mobile, so if you want different behavior, you should remove that from your Grid component too.

Because of what you are trying to do, it probably makes more sense to move the sizing definitions down to your Grid.Column components exclusively. You can technically achieve the same "stackable" behavior by just defining the mobile column width to sixteen. Defining your sizing at the Grid.Column level gives you the most control.

Basically, if what you have defined on your Grid.Column components right now is explicitly defining what you want, removing "stackable" and "columns" props from your Grid component should give you what you want since you are controlling widths at the more precise Grid.Column level.